# UIStepper not displaying when it is contained in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistepper

When I put a `UIStepper` in a `UITableViewCell` with Storyboard or make stepper in cell programmatically,

```
UIStepper* stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] init];
stepper.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10);
[cell.contentView insertSubview:stepper atIndex:1000];
```

it does not display in iOS 7 but when I do the same thing in iOS 6, it works.

Why doesn't it display in iOS 7?

Comment: oh, and when i try press plus or minus button on stappe in ios7 it works, but it not displayed;

Comment: What about `[cell addSubview:stepper]`? It is still a UIView.